# select a columns not exist in another tables multiple columns in sql

Tags: hive, subquery, conditional-statements, not-exists

I have two tables Tables1 with ID, name, and Table2 has ID1, ID2, and ID3, name1, name2, and name3.
I want to select table1.ID not exists in tables2: ID1, ID2, and ID3

```
select T1.ID,t1.name
from table1 t1
where  not exists (
   SELECT *
   FROM table2 t2
where t1.ID=t2.ID1  or t1.ID=t2.ID2 or or t1.ID=t2.ID3  )
```

I get error message for this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I could find [this](http://www.hadooplessons.info/2017/08/usage-of-subqueries-in-apache-hive.html). Basically, you can't have multiple columns for a subquery in a `IN` or a `NOT IN` condition in the `WHERE` clause. This is why your query is currently failing : Your subquery get all the columns from Table2.

---

From my understanding of your question, you want a select where the results would be the elements that are not existing in Table2.

To do this, you can simply use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. In SQL, I would left join on all three columns, but it seems like Hive does not support multiple conditions in `JOIN` statements, so you can use the following alternative :

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.name
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2_1 ON T2_1.ID1 = T1.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2_2 ON T2_2.ID2 = T1.ID
    WHERE (T2_1.id IS NULL) AND                  -- the id of Table2 - T2_1    
          (T2_2.id IS NULL)                      -- the id of Table2 - T2_2
```

Just add as many `LEFT JOIN` and conditions in the `WHERE` clause as you have columns to check.

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ca17f/9) with this query concept (the data are not the same, but the concept is).

Comment: I want to select table1.ID not exists in tables2: ID1, ID2, and ID3 columns. select t1.ID, ti.name
from table1 t1
where t1.ID not in (
select t2.ID1, t2.ID2,t2.ID3
from table2 t2)
it is not working . Error message: SubQuery can contain only 1 item in Select List

Comment: then you can add multiple conditions to the inner join with `OR` or `AND`

Comment: Hi Sirmyself, it is not supported on ON (T2.ID1 = T1.ID OR
                            T2.ID2 = T1.ID)

Comment: I checked and the query works with two `LEFT JOIN` I will edit my answer

Comment: Hi Simyself , the left join one is good, could you edit your answer and I will accept is as answer-Thanks

Comment: @anson You are very welcome. I already edited my answer. The final query is at the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Join first by `ID1`, then resulted dataset join by `ID2`, then resulted dataset join by `ID3`:

```
select  p2.ID, p2.name       --pass3
 from
  (select p1.ID, p1.name     --pass2
     from
      (SELECT T1.ID, T1.name --pass1
         FROM Table1 T1
         LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID    
        where T2.ID1 is null                        --not in ID1
      ) p1 LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID2 = p1.ID 
    where T2.ID1 is null                            --also not in ID2
  ) p2 LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID3 = p2.ID
where T2.ID1 is null                                --also not in ID3
```

Joins on 2 and 3 steps will receive already reduced dataset from T1 and this solution may be good for big tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,NAME
FROM
(SELECT T1.ID, T1.name
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID
where T2.ID1 is null
union
SELECT T1.ID, T1.name
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID2 = T1.ID
where T2.ID2 is null
union
SELECT T1.ID, T1.name
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID3 = T1.ID
where T2.ID3 is null)JO
```

Comment: It's most likely you get duplicated from this query and you filter the 3 columns individually, which means you may get data where the id is equal to one of `ID1`, `ID2` or `ID3`.

Comment: He needs OR condition not AND condition. I think you have no working knowledge in Hive. There are limitations in Hive.

Comment: I think I have enough knowledge to actually know what this query does. Even if there are limitations in hive, with this query, you grab any data that is at least not referenced once in one of the three columns. So it gives you too much data according to what OP wanted.